# GridViewColumn content and VerticalAlignment

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, gridviewcolumn

i want to display some information in a listview using the GridView.
i have several GridViewColumns and everything works fine.

However, want the GridViewColumns content to have a VerticalAlignment (Top in this case) 
but the gridvewcolumn intself doesnt offer a VerticalContentAlignment dependency property.
when using DisplayMemberBinding there is also no possibility to supply
VerticalAlignment information.

When using a custom DataTemplate as Celltemplate, i can add a VerticalAlignment="top" dp to e.g. some textblock. however this does not work.
is there any "nifty-grifty special magic trick" to fullfill this tasK?
(

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can apply this style to your `ListView`:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: This would override default style, so more often than not it can't be accepted.